# pytest parameters execution order for repeated test seems to be wrong

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run a test repeatedly which is a paramertrized. it doesn't seem to follow the order while executing test. I tried using pytest-repeat and pytest.mark.parametrize but i still didn't get the desired outcome.
The code is

*conftest.py*

```
scenarios = [('first', {'attribute': 'value'}), ('second', {'attribute': 'value'})]
id = [scenario[0] for scenario in scenarios]
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", params=scenarios, ids=id)
def **get_scenario**(request):
  return request.param
```

*test_param.py*

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("count",range(3))
def test_scenarios(get_scenario,count):
    assert get_scenario
```

When i execute

```
py.test test_param.py
```

The result i get is

```
test_scenarios[first-0]
test_scenarios[first-1]
test_scenarios[first-2]
test_scenarios[second-0]
test_scenarios[second-1]
test_scenarios[second-2]
```

The result iam **expecting is**

```
test_scenarios[first-0]
test_scenarios[second-0]
test_scenarios[first-1]
test_scenarios[second-1]
test_scenarios[first-2]
test_scenarios[second-2]
```

Is there any way i can make it work like as the test  **"first"** sets the date and **"second"** unsets the data , hence i need to maintain the order so that i can run repeat the tests. These test are basically for performance profiling which measures the time for setting the data and clearing the data by API. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to do it. Instead of having **scenarios** in conftest i moved it in a test and then using pytest.mark.parametrize. pytest groups the params instead of executing as a list one by one. anyway the way i achieved is as follows : ***Remember the count order should be close to the test method***

*test_param.py*

```
scenarios = [('first', {'attribute': 'value'}), ('second', {'attribute': 'value'})]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_id,scenario",scenarios)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("count",range(3)) #Remember the order , if you move it first then it will not run it the order i desired i-e first,second,first second
def test_scenarios(test_id,scenario,count):
   assert scenario["attribute"] == "value"
```

The output will be

```
test_scenario[0-first-scenario0]
test_scenario[0-second-scenario1]
test_scenario[1-first-scenario0]
test_scenario[1-second-scenario1]
test_scenario[2-first-scenario0]
test_scenario[2-second-scenario1]
```

Hope this helps