# How to customize the pytest name

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to customize the output name of my pytest to include the name of my fixtures

So I have

```
def test_t1(
    when_creating_a_project_from_a_sales_handoff,
    with_a_new_customer,
    and_no_conflicting_data_exists,
    create_project):
it_will_create_a_customer_with_the_releavant_information()
it_will_create_a_project_that_references_the_newly_created_customer()
```

and I'd like the displayed test name to be some version of

```
when_creating_a_project_from_a_sales_handoff
with_a_new_customer
and_no_conflicting_data_exists
create_project
```

How can I do this? I tried creating

```
@fixture
def namer(request):
    request.node.name = 'test_foo'
```

but no dice, it didn't change the test display name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to change the displayed name, but only by using pytest private variables.

Make a `conftest.py`file and make this function:

```
def pytest_itemcollected(item):
    """ change test name, using fixture names """
    item._nodeid = ', '.join(item._fixtureinfo.argnames)
```

When I run this test_file with pytest:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def fixture_1():
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def fixture_2():
    pass

def test1(fixture_1):
    assert 1 == 1

def test_a(fixture_1, fixture_2):
    assert 1 == 2
```

The result is:

```
pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: C:\Users\gelineau\Desktop\kaggle_flavien, inifile:
collected 2 items                                                              

fixture_1 .                                                              [ 50%]
fixture_1, fixture_2 F                                                   [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_a ____________________________________

fixture_1 = None, fixture_2 = None

    def test_a(fixture_1, fixture_2):
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

test\test_so.py:15: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.86 seconds ======================
```

The new test names are also printed in pycharm